# How do I save files to different directories? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that downloads pictures from reddit but it saves them to the folder with my py file.

How can I save these pictures to a folder called pictures?

```
import os

filename = "17861.jpg"
path = "E:\projects\python\Yuki.py\pic saver\pictures"
fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

I have tried this but it would not work.

If you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Either do `"E:\\projects\\python\\Yuki.py\\pic saver\\pictures"` or `r"E:\projects\python\Yuki.py\pic saver\pictures"`

Comment: raw strings are a must for Windoze users.  You might be able to get away with using /s;  Give it  a whirl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslashes have special meaning in Python strings.  You can either use the `r` prefix to make it a raw string (`r"E:\projects\python\Yuki.py\pic saver\pictures"`), or double the backslashes (`"E:\\projects\\python\\Yuki.py\\pic saver\\pictures"`), or use forward slashes.  All Windows APIs accept forward slashes (`"E:/projects/python/Yuki.py/pic saver/pictures")`.